# Unique data best approach

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables,

- TABLE A (id, some_data)
- TABLE B (id, some_data)

Table A gets filled all the time, about 400 records / sec and there are lots of data that is
the same inside.

I need Table B that shows only unique data in it from Table A for a specific column.

My approach would be to have trigger (on insert) for Table A and check if that data is already present in Table B, if isn't just insert it there.

Can someone point for a better solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a compelling reason to store duplicate data in the first place?

Comment: Performancewise (possibly), it sounds better then using select distinct every time on whole data set

Comment: Better than running 400 triggers per second? Take some measurements. I don't think there's any harm in writing the trigger for testing. Use an existing example as a template. Develop and run in a test database first, not your production database.

Comment: How does data get into table "A"?